# MaxSAT/MaxSMT examples

Tags: z3

I have find "MaxSAT/MaxSMT examples" at the following links
[http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group_*maxsat*_ex.html](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__maxsat__ex.html)
but it only provides C code.

I am interested in how it is coded using Z3 directly? Could someone kindly provide me with an example? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main purpose of the MaxSAT/MaxSMT example in the Z3 documentation is to demonstrate how to use the API `Z3_check_assumptions` to implement two different procedures for MaxSAT. The example contains several comments explaining the basic ideas and a reference to paper due to Fu and Malik. The paper has a detailed description of the algorithm used in the `fu_malik_maxsat` procedure in this example. There are also other MaxSAT algorithms that can be implemented in the top of the Z3 API.

The Z3 SMT 2.0 front-end (i.e., the z3 executable) does not have direct support for MaxSAT/MaxSMT.
However, assumptions can be provided to the `check-sat` command. 
Users interested in MaxSAT should use the MaxSAT example as a starting point.